# problem with solving a set of equations using ODE solvers in matlab

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, matlab, mathematical-modeling

I have used matlab ode solvers to solve equations of the form: $$dy/dt=f(y,t)$$ in other words, where for instance say with an explicit Euler time stepping $$y^{n+1}=y^{n}+\Delta t f(y^n,t)$$ Is it possible to use ODE solvers to (simultaneously or otherwise) solve the system of two equations in the form:
$$\left\{ \begin{array}{c}
x^{n+1}\\
y^{n+1}
\end{array}\right\} =\left\{ \begin{array}{c}
x^{n}+\Delta t\,g\left(x^{n},t\right)\\
\frac{x^{n}y^{n}+\Delta t\,f\left(y^{n},x^{n},t\right)}{x^{n+1}}
\end{array}\right\} $$
where f and g are arbitrary functions, n refers to the nth time step, t is time and x and y are variables.

Comment: did you try in matlab with $y(t)$ being a function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^n$ ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Like I've said, I know how to use ode solvers in Maltab. My problem is with solving the two equations together as one system, with x appearing at two time steps. I have never come across this (where the f or g are function of variables at different time steps) in the documentation

Comment: It should be easy to program the loop. To use an ODE solver, you need an actual ODE (system). My answer shows how to read your equation as Euler step of an ODE system which then can also be solved by ode45 or others. Please clarify the direction of your question.

Comment: Please read my question carefully. I know how to write a code, my question is specifically on ODE solver. As stated in the equation, is it possible to use ode solvers to solve a problem like the one I have!!

Comment: To repeat: To use an ODE solver, you need an actual ODE. Your last equation is a discrete dynamical system, but not a differential equation. Thus it can not be solved by ODE solvers.

Comment: Finally, the answer to my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Define $z=x·y$, then your second equation is
$$
z^{n+1}=z^n+Δt·f(z^n/x^n,x^n,t^n)
$$
resp. the Euler step for $\dot z=f(y/x,x,t)$.

Then you can solve the equation as a coupled system as usual.

---

If you want to get $y$ directly, use $\dot z = \dot x·y+x·\dot y$ to find
$$
\dot y = \frac{f(y,x,t)-g(x,t)·y}{x}
$$
as the second equation of the system.

Comment: This not what I'm after. That is just live solving a single equation (my first equation with y replaced with z = xy). My x in the second equation appears in two time steps.

Comment: I'll edit the question to make it more clear

Comment: That is accounted for in $z^{n+1}=x^{n+1}·y^{n+1}$ resp. $y^{n+1}=z^{n+1}/x^{n+1}$.

Comment: I want to use the information (x^n+1) in solving the second equation (x_n+1 appears on the right hand side of 2nd equation), you are solving d(xy)/dt=f(x,y,t) but I want d(xy)/dt = (1/x_n+1)*f(x,y,t)

Comment: There is no $x^{n+1}$ in any differential equation. $n$ is some time step index in the numerical solution, it has no place in the original ODE. If you can clarify that, then your question is probably 90% solved.

Comment: I want to use the information (x^n+1) from my first equation on the right hand side of my second equation. I know this can be done using other time stepping schemes, where the first equation is solved before the second one, etc... what I want to know is if somehow I can do that with ode solvers. my guess is that there is not a way, but I wanted to make sure.

Comment: As repeatedly said, the only thing you can solve with ODE solvers are ODE. The thing with $x^{n+1}$ inside is not an ODE, and frankly, I do not see what there is to *solve*, this is a very explicit computational instruction.